# How do I change the default language in the Symfony 2.6.0

Tags: php, symfony

I use Symfony 2.6.0
I need to set the language of the user instead of the default language.
Services to change locale:

```
 helper.interactive_login_listener:
        class: HelperBundle\Listeners\LanguageListener
        calls:
            - [ setSession, [@session] ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: setLocaleForAuthenticatedUser }

 helper.language.kernel_request_listener:
        class: HelperBundle\Listeners\LanguageListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser }
```

Code:

```
namespace HelperBundle\Listeners;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class LanguageListener
{
    private $session;

    public function setSession(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * kernel.request event. If a guest user doesn't have an opened session, locale is equal to
     * "undefined" as configured by default in parameters.ini. If so, set as a locale the user's
     * preferred language.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {

        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $request->setLocale('ru');

    }

    /**
     * security.interactive_login event. If a user chose a language in preferences, it would be set,
     * if not, a locale that was set by setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser remains.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent $event
     */
    public function setLocaleForAuthenticatedUser(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {

        $this->session->set('_locale', 'ru');

    }
}
```

Config:

```
framework:
    translator:      ~
    default_locale:  ~
```

In Controller:

```
namespace HelperBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

abstract class PrototypeController extends Controller
{
    protected $model;
    protected $flashBag;

    //Метод загрузки модели контроллера
    abstract function loadServiceModelEvent($model_service_name);

    //Вывод шаблона
    protected function renderPage($template, $response)
    {
        print $this->get('request')->getLocale().'==';
        print $this->get('request')->getSession()->get('_locale'); die();
```

Result print:

```
ru==ru
```

At the same time, English (en) is used.
But, if set

```
framework:

translator:      ~
default_locale:  ru
```

Then everything is fine.
How to change language?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "at the same time"?

Comment: Used  default locale. "ru" locale not activated. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the problem is that the language is not set properly by your listener. Problem with listeners in this case is, that you cannot set priority for their execution. That is when EventSubscriber comes to the party.

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.exception_subscriber:
        class: AppBundle\EventSubscriber\LanguageListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Your listener in that case will sth like this:

```
class LanguageListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $session;

    public function setSession(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [
                ['onKernelRequest', 9],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

As you can see the difference is not big, BUT in the `getSubscribedEvents` function you can specify the priority which will be used (in this case 9). You can read more about the priorities in the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html).

You need to make sure, that the subscriber will be executed before the initialization of `LocaleListener` from the Symfony framework. That listener (actually subscriber) "messes up" with the settings and sets the defaults if othing is there. So if you intercept the locale before, it should work pretty fine.

You can check all the registered listeners and subscribers via CLI command:

```
php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher
```

Comment: You can set a priority on both event listeners and subscribers.

Comment: That is maybe possible but even the official documentation does not say anything about that, it only mention `priority` setup for subscribers. I never tried to alter the priority for listener :-)